# Quintic polynomial problem without analysis

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Just wondering: Is there a purely algebraic proof of the existence of an irreducible quintic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with exactly three real roots? Sure, it's easy to give concrete examples, but I don't see how the proof of the polynomial having exactly three real roots can avoid using completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ in the form of some intermediate/mean value theorem-type methods (that's what I mean by purely algebraic).

Comment: The Galois group of such a polynomial is full $S_5$, because it is transitive and contains a 2-cycle (=the complex conjugation). All its ten transpositions are conjugate, so with suitable relabeling any one of them could be the complex conjugation. Hmm. That doesn't actually say anything about your question. Except that we will be in the unsolvable by radicals case. Come to think of it, what would you accept as a purely algebraic method of identifying a real number as such? An interesting question nevertheless!

Comment: How about simply taking Stevin's definition of real numbers via infinite decimal expansions without ever mentioning completeness?